# Compatibility of Visual Studio 2012 app in older OS

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, compatibility, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am planning of creating a application in Visual Sudio Pro 2012 in future. I want the app to run in XP, Vista, 7 and 8. So, does the app created in Visual Studio Pro will work on these OS or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application targets .Net 3.5 or 4.0, then it should be able to run on your desired operating systems (subject to having installed the framework), irrespective of the version of Windows on which it was developed. (Of course, you'd still want to *test* on all the platforms you're going to support)

Comment: You can target later versions of .NET - if you use something like ClickOnce installation it will check for and install the correct version of .NET for you.

Comment: Worth noting that 4.5 is only available for Windows Vista and later, so would not work for Windows XP

Comment: Good point, I'd forgotten that wrinkle.

Comment: I think I can also use .Net 3.0 with Visual Studio 2012. Am I right. I'm asking just because I have never use VB.net earlier in my life

Comment: Here is more information about compatibility of .Net with older OS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb822049.aspx